# Getting container of a void pointer

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am currently trying to get rid of a backref I need for the following function:

```
/**
 * amd_sfh_hid_poll - Updates the input report for a HID device.
 * @work:   The delayed work
 *
 * Polls input reports from the respective HID devices and submits
 * them by invoking hid_input_report() from hid-core.
 */
static void amd_sfh_hid_poll(struct work_struct *work)
{
    struct amd_sfh_hid_data *hid_data;
    struct hid_device *hid;
    size_t size;
    u8 *buf;

    hid_data = container_of(work, struct amd_sfh_hid_data, work.work);
    hid = hid_data->hid;
    size = get_descriptor_size(hid_data->sensor_idx, AMD_SFH_INPUT_REPORT);

    buf = kzalloc(size, GFP_KERNEL);
    if (!buf) {
        hid_err(hid, "Failed to allocate memory for input report!\n");
        goto reschedule;
    }

    size = get_input_report(hid_data->sensor_idx, 1, buf, size,
                            hid_data->cpu_addr);
    if (size < 0) {
        hid_err(hid, "Failed to get input report!\n");
        goto free_buf;
    }

    hid_input_report(hid, HID_INPUT_REPORT, buf, size, 0);

free_buf:
    kfree(buf);
reschedule:
    schedule_delayed_work(&hid_data->work, hid_data->interval);
}
```

The [`struct amd_sfh_hid_data`](https://github.com/conqp/linux/blob/amd-sfh/drivers/hid/amd-sfh-hid/amd-sfh-hid-ll-drv.h#L28) is the driver data stored under `hid->driver_data` for the respective 
[`struct hid_device`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/hid.h#L545). Within the work queue, I need to access the HID's driver data and from that the HID device, which I currently do by accessing the backref `hid = hid_data->hid`.
I now tried to get rid of the backref by using `container_of` on the driver data:

```
hid = container_of((void*)hid_data, struct hid_device, driver_data);
```

But this results in page faults, as does

```
hid = container_of((void**)*hid_data, struct hid_device, driver_data);
```

What is the correct way to get a `struct hid_device *` given its member `void *driver_data` using `container_of`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the correct way to get a `struct hid_device *` given its member `void *driver_data` using `container_of`?

No way.

Usage of `container_of` implies that you have a **pointer to a member**, not a *value* of a member, as in your case.

Short example:

```
struct B;
struct C;

struct A {
   struct B field1;
   struct C* field2;
}
```

Having a **pointer** to the `field1`, using `container_of` you may got a pointer to the whole `struct A` object.

Having a **value** of `field2` (even it has a type `struct C*`, that is pointer), you cannot get a pointer to the `struct A` object.

Comment: I thought as much. Thank you for the clarification.